# How to design unit tests for creating an object in which user can set many values?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Supose that I have to create an object which the use can set many vaules, for example 10 values. And this object has another values that are set by the system according to the values given by the uesr.

Is is a good idea create all the test doing all the possible combinations of the values that the user can set? Because in this case, if a value can have 5 possible values, another 3, another 6... all the combinations can be so much although for a small method.

Another case is a property that is set by the system and it doesn't depend on the values that can set the user, for example, the date of modification. For example:

```
MyClass
{
    Property01;
    Property02;
    Property03;
    ModificationDate;
}


method01(int param01, int param02, paramObject)
{
    paramObject.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;

    if(param01 < 0 && param02 > 0)
    {
        paramObject.ModificationDate = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01);
    }
}
```

In this case, if I don't test all the possibles values of the int, or at least when it is lower than 0 and bigger than 0, I couldn't find the error, becase supone that I test only a case where param01 is bigger than 0, I wouldn't be able to detect the error.

But this case is easy, what would happen if I have more parameters, or more possible values for the parameters? The combination would be so big really.

In general, I would like to know some common practice to test objects that can have many values, because at the beggining I started to considerate to try all the possibles combination of all possibles values of the parameters, but in some cases it amount of work that makes me think if there is not a better aproach.

Thanks.

Comment: You can create a parametrized unit test to separate actual test logic from test data

Comment: check Nunit testing framework, it has some handy attributes like 'TestCase'

Answer (score 0):

The number of combinations may become huge, but most likely only if you design your test cases with a black box approach.

In practice, code that has to distinguish between different parameter constellations typically follows a divide-and-conquer approach: Early in the code some fundamental distinctions are made.

For example, functions often check first whether the input arguments are in a valid range.  The cases where there are invalid arguments are then handled separately (sometimes causing exceptions, or leading to an early exit of the function).

When doing glass box testing you can benefit from the knowledge about this approach: You don't have to create a cartesian product of all inputs with all combinations of valid and invalid inputs: For testing whether invalid inputs are detected and handled correctly you have test cases focusing on one input at a time: To test if invalid data for input `i1` is detected, you provide all other inputs with valid data and only `i1` gets invalid data.  Similarly for the other inputs.  Thus, you can ignore combinations like 'i1' invalid and `i2` invalid and `i3` invalid.

Such glass box knowledge can help to reduce the amount of test cases tremendously.  It comes at a price, however: When you change your implementation, you will also have to adjust your test cases.  Moreover, with glass box testing you may overlook some scenarios of relevance.  But, all in all its a tradeoff to end up with an amount of test cases that can be handled.